# Logger Not Working

Tags: magento24

I'm currently working on a Magento 2 project and encountering issues with the "custom logger" when attempting to use it in developer mode. I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot this problem.

```
"custom logger"

Magento 2 version: 2.4.6
Logger used:  $this->logger->debug()
```

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2, the debug logs take time to load if the object is collection, e.g, product collection or any other information about the object that you are debugging.

```
$this->logger->debug()
```

For the newest of, Magento 2.4.3+, use below code:

```
 $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
```

if that not work, you can install the **Laminas** package for the logger print using `composer require laminas/laminas-log`

then use below code:

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

// $logger has log methods for different priorities like warning, notice, error, etc.
$logger->info('Hello World!');
$logger->notice('Hello World!');
$logger->warn('Hello World!');
```

please note: Magento 2.4.3 removes this module

Also, you can use the below code:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug('Your Message');
```

For the full detailed description check this: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-logs/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logger for only testing purpose, you can use direct code either use proper magento standard

With Magento 2.4.4 & plus versions use below code:

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/testing.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Test the log');
$logger->info(var_dump($yourVariable));
```